# Can we delete the last node of a Single Linked list if we only know the address of last node

Tags: singly-linked-list

// Variables

```
typedef struct node 
 { 
    int value; 
    struct node *next; 
 }mynode;
```

// Globals (not required, though).

```
mynode *head, *tail, *temp;
```

// Functions

```
void add(int value);
```

// Function to add new nodes to the linked list

```
 void add(int value)
 {
    temp = (mynode *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->next=(mynode *)0;
    temp->value=value;

    if(head==(mynode *)0)
    {
       head=temp;
       tail=temp;
    }
    else
    {
      tail->next=temp;
      tail=temp;
    }
 }
```

// The main() function

```
int main()
 {
     head=(mynode *)0;

     // Construct the linked list.
     add(1);
     add(2);
     add(3);

     return(0);
 }
```

If I only have a pointer to a node, whose value is 3(The Last node as seen in the aforementioned code) , Can we delete it and make a node whose value is 2(aforementioned code) as the last node.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the [homework] tag.

Comment: Nopes, just came across the question on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but if you know what you are doing, you can modify the last node in-place. Deleting the last node requires access to the second-to-last node, and specifically its link to the last node.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not. Unless you have some reference to previous node. like head pointer. If you have other reference than its pretty much easier. In fact if you don't have any pointers you will loose the list itself

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.. Try the following code:

```
void deleteNode()
{
    mynode *temp1;
    for(temp1 = head; temp->next!= tail; temp1 = temp1->next);
    tail = temp1;
    free(tail->next);
}
```

It will delete the last node.

Comment: you mean you only have last node address....??? Node will get deleted but you will lose the list...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

You can call `free` on that pointer to the last node, but that just means that the memory occupied by that node is no longer claimed. The data will most likely stay there unchanged for a while. And that means that the next-to-last node's pointer to it is still valid, even though it should not be.

To delete the node in a way that is meaningful to the list, that pointer contained in the next-to-last node has to be nullified. And that can't be done unless that next-to-last node can be accessed, either by a direct pointer to it, or by traversing the list from a preceding node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a doubly linked list to access the previous node. Or iterate through the entire list.