# Is it possible to delete the last node in a linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

For example, there is an exercise that says:

> Write a function to delete a node from a linked list, given only that pointer

And this is the solution:

```
void deleteNode(Node* toDelete) {

    // this function essensially first copies the data from the next pointer
    // and then, deletes the next pointer
    // However, it doesn't work if trying to delete the last element in the list

    Node *temp = toDelete->next;    // create a temp, assign to the one after toDelete
    toDelete->data = temp->data;    // change toDelete's data to the one's after it
    toDelete->next = temp->next;    // change toDelete's next to the one's after it

    delete temp;
    temp = nullptr;
}
```

How can I alter my solution to be able to delete the **last** element in the linked list, given **only** the pointer last node?

Comment: How is the last node different to other nodes, and how could you test for that?

Comment: It points to nothing? it's next is a nullptr

Comment: So maybe you can use that information to do something different for that node.

Comment: You need a doubly linked list. Or if you have a reference to the head of the list, you can traverse the list until you reach the element before the one to be deleted.

Comment: @Clyde that would be too easy :D I'm not allowed to change the structure

Comment: Why are you using free functions instead of a list class? To delete the last node is actually not the problem, but if you want to delete something in the middle you will break the chain because you cannot access the previous node. Either use a class that stores a pointer to the beginning of the list, or a doubly linked list.

Comment: @juanchopanza I could..... just delete it and make it a null ptr?

Comment: Given __only__ a pointer to the node, there is no way to reach the previous node in the list to _unlink_ it from the list.

Comment: Well, if it's a singly linked list, and you don't have access to the head of the list, you can't do it.

Comment: *If* you can delete a node in the middle, *then* deleting the last node is easier. But I don't see how you can correctly delete a node in the middle in a simple singly linked list.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288237/can-we-delete-the-last-node-of-a-single-linked-list-if-we-only-know-the-address

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously you can't; the previous node points to a valid node, and there's no way to change that.

What you could do is add a sentinel node to the end of the list. You would never remove that node, and never use it to store data. Then your solution will work for all data nodes. This doesn't require any changes to the node structure, but does require changes to the way you iterate over the list.

Comment: I wonder whether that would be forbidden under "I'm not allowed to change the structure" or not. I assumed it would, but I'm giving you +1 for assuming it wouldn't :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible with a singly-linked list.

The reason is that you need to modify the penultimate node (to make its `next` pointer null). But there is no way of finding that node from the last node.

In general, you cannot remove a node from a singly-linked list given only a pointer to the node.

What you're currently doing is essentially a "cheat", since you aren't really deleting the node pointed to. You're mutating the list and then deleting the successor of the node pointed to. This makes a difference if some other bit of code somewhere is holding a pointer to that successor when you call this function -- their pointer gets invalidated. So you're removing the data element pointed to, but you aren't removing the node pointed to.

Comment: Just to be clear: this would apply to all nodes, not just the last one, right?

Comment: @juanchopanza: agreed. I was editing to say that, but then I got into the explanation of why the questioner's current code might look like it deletes the node pointed to, but actually doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

In order to handle deletion of a node in a single linked list like that you would need to modify the node before and after.

```
            +-----+  +----------+  +------+
header----->|     |->| toDelete |->|      |
            +-----+  +----------+  +------+
```

you would need a pointer to the first element of the list since otherwise it is impossible to do what you want due to the nature of the data structure.

first you find the node before the one you need to delete e.g.

```
Node* before = header;
for (;before->next != toDelete; before = before->next) {;}
```

now do `before->next = toDelete->next` if `toDelete` is the last node it will be a nullptr otherwise a pointer to the next node

(of course you need to delete what the `toDelete` points to in both cases)